# Access Internet Explorer Downloads List

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I want to access Internet Explorer Download List

[image: Screenshot of the download list]

I tried to access History with `UrlHistoryWrapperClass` but that does not give me path of the downloaded file.

I need Filename, FilePath and URL aswell.

My problem is accessing View Downloads list of internet explorer. If anyone achieved that before, i appriicate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm agree with GregN. As far as I know, we have no approach to get the download list directly. The closest approach we can take is to get the history in IE. You could refer to [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7500/The-Tiny-Wrapper-Class-for-URL-History-Interface-i) about how to read IE history using `UrlHistoryLibrary`. In the example, we can get the urls of IE history.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are able to get this information from the history (unless there is an exploit I'm not aware of).  The best you can do is go through the history and if needed, you can trigger a webclient to re-download the file.  Attached is a generic example for Internet Explorer for at least traversing the history:

```
public class InternetExplorer
{
// List of URL objects
public List<URL> URLs { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<URL> GetHistory()
{
    // Initiate main object
    UrlHistoryWrapperClass urlhistory = new UrlHistoryWrapperClass();

    // Enumerate URLs in History
    UrlHistoryWrapperClass.STATURLEnumerator enumerator =
    urlhistory.GetEnumerator();

    // Iterate through the enumeration
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Obtain URL and Title
        string url = enumerator.Current.URL.Replace('\'', ' ');
        // In the title, eliminate single quotes to avoid confusion
        string title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumerator.Current.Title)
        ? enumerator.Current.Title.Replace('\'', ' ') : "";

        // Create new entry
        URL U = new URL(url, title, "Internet Explorer");

        // Add entry to list
        URLs.Add(U);
    }

    // Optional
    enumerator.Reset();

    // Clear URL History
    urlhistory.ClearHistory();

    return URLs;
}
```

Comment: I Tried this and the problem with this approach is the download links are protected via Session, so reopening them or creating a connection to them to download is not possible.